# Missing 80% of GET responses

Tags: node.js, aerospike

Our company is planning on transitioning from REDIS to Aerospike, but we are seeing some strange issues with missing get requests (only 35% making it back to the callback function).

Here is the code we are testing with:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) 
    {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
    }
} 
else 
{

    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var requests = 0;
    var responses = 0;

    var aerospike = require('./node_modules/aerospike');
    var status = aerospike.status;

    var client = aerospike.client({
        hosts: [
            { addr: '127.0.0.1', port: 3000 } 
        ]
    });

    function connect_cb( err, client) {
        if (err.code == status.AEROSPIKE_OK) {
            console.log("Aerospike Connection Success")
        }
    }

    client.connect(connect_cb)

    setInterval(function(){
        for(var i=0; i<50; i++)
        {
            var key = aerospike.key('dexi','toys','floor_'+i);
            requests++;
            client.get(key, function(err, rec, meta) {
                responses++;
                if ( err.code == status.AEROSPIKE_OK ) 
                {

                }
                else 
                {
                    console.error('Get Error:', err);
                }
            });


        }
    },10);

    setInterval(function(){
        for(var i=0; i<50; i++)
        {
            var key = aerospike.key('dexi','toys','floor_'+i);
            var rec = { 
              uid:    1000,  // integer data stored in bin called "uid"
              name:   "user_name", // string data stored in bin called "user_name"
              dob:    { mm: 12, dd: 29, yy: 1995},  // map data stored (msgpack format) in bin called "dob" 
              friends: [1001, 1002, 1003]
             };

            var metadata = {
                ttl: 10000,
                gen: 0
            };
            client.put(key, rec, metadata, function(err) {
                switch ( err.code ) {
                    case status.AEROSPIKE_OK:
                        break;

                    default:
                        console.error("Put Error: " + err.message);
                        exitCode = 1;
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    },10);

    setInterval(function(){
        var timeSpent = ( new Date().getTime()) - start;
        console.log(requests, responses,timeSpent);
    },15000);

}
```

Below is the console output we are seeing:

```
34400 9306 15098
34150 9250 15080
35050 9330 15087
34150 9235 15092
33250 9310 15120
33950 9249 15090
34650 9298 15101
35000 9400 15102
34700 9300 15166
33150 9399 15181
34500 9300 15193
33850 9292 15207
34400 9250 15162
34100 9360 15212
34050 9250 15171
34100 9348 15159
33800 9250 15118
34300 9309 15189
34050 9300 15152
34250 9405 15181
```

As you can see, on average, for every 35k get requests we send, we are only seeing a small % of them actually come back. Our Aerospike dashboard also reflects the discrepancy (only seeing 35% of the gets sent), as the throughput is reflecting the responses we are getting back.

Comment: `Our Aerospike dashboard also reflects this`; reflects what?  That it's receiving 35k calls or that it's receiving 9k calls?

Comment: Edited the question. It's reflecting 9k calls.

Comment: Have you ruled out network issues?

Comment: Linked to https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/missing-80-of-get-responses/1223